# Using AWS Elasticache Redis to manage sessions in Sails.js

Tags: redis, sails.js, amazon-elasticache

I'm currently using connect-redis in my Sails.js project to leverage a locally-installed redis instance.  In the future, I'd like to use a common redis instance for multiple server instances (behind a load balancer), so I've been looking at AWS Elasticache.  I'm having trouble with the configuration, though.

*sails-project\config\session.js:*

```
adapter: 'connect-redis',
host: 'primary-endpoint.xxxxxx.ng.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com',
port: 6379,
ttl: <redis session TTL in seconds>,
db: 0,
pass: <redis auth password>,
prefix: 'sess:',
```

What should the TTL value be?  Should the pass attribute point to IAM somehow?

I tried creating a user in IAM with AmazonElastiCacheFullAccess permissions and putting its access key ID in the `pass` attribute, but I got this error in my server console (testing on my Windows box):

```
C:\repos\sails-project\node_modules\connect-redis\lib\connect-redis.js:83
      throw err;
      ^
AbortError: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed.
    at RedisClient.flush_and_error (C:\repos\sails-project\node_modules\redis\index.js:362:23)
...
```

Any ideas on what to change?

Comment: I guess the TTL is whatever you deem fit for your application based on how long you want the session to be active for.

As for the IAM stuff. 1) I don't think an IAM user is going to work here? It's asking you for an Elasticache username and password not an AWS username/password. 2) Redis is open by default so you won't need to authenticate (that's not to say you shouldn't, but you should look at the Redis native way to do this).

Comment: Yeah, when I'm running redis on the same instance as the server, I don't supply any credentials in the configuration. I assume authentication would be required when pointing to a different server, though.  As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be any "Elasticache username," though, so I'm puzzled on how to piece these together (or if it's even possible).

Comment: Yeah it is a little odd. The last I heard is that the elasticache redis service should be locked down by security groups and that's it. If you need further control then spawn redis on EC2.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume your "windows box" is outside of AWS.

For Elasticache you can't access it from outside AWS. See the Security Section here : https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/faqs/#Can_I_access_Amazon_ElastiCache_from_outside_AWS

The most common use case is to have EC2 instances within a VPC access and consume the Elasticache service. Along with this the Elasticache Redis service doesn't employ authentication and only allows lock down via security groups.

If you need something that differentiates from this configuration then you should look at putting Redis on EC2 so that you have full control.

Comment: Aha, you're right!  I've been testing on my laptop only, so far.  I didn't try on AWS, since I figured it was due to a bug in the code.  I'll try testing on AWS, as you suggest.